# Install Server 2003 from USB

Tags: usb, installation, windows-server-2003, bootable-media

I need some way to boot my windows server 2003 install from a USB drive , any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Hi i have tried both answers below and none of them worked , mostly because they either were directed at linux or too old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did this last week using [wintoflash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/).  I didn't have an install cd or ISO, just a network share with all the setup files.  Worked well enough to get the installation up and running, but I had to hunt down the cd2 files on the network in order to install the "extra components".

Comment: Doesn't work for a few operating systems, notably Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find a nice tutorial [**here**](https://old.windowsvalley.com/install-windows-2000-xp-2003-using-usb-storage-device-pen-drive/) on how to put the install of Windows Server 2003 (and 2000, Server 2000 and XP) on a USB drive.

Comment: Updated link: http://old.windowsvalley.com/install-windows-2000-xp-2003-using-usb-storage-device-pen-drive/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Windows USB/DVD Download Tool only supports Windows XP SP2, Windows Vista, or Windows 7. [More info](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool).**

I have been using Windows 7 USB Download Tool.  Which is very simple to use.  All you need is ISO and with this tool open, plug in USB drive - point the ISO file to USB and off you go!  The utility is FREE from Microsoft Windows

Link: [Windows 7 USB Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool)

Hope this helps!

Cheers!